# Asp.net performance counters for to getting number of concurrent users (user load) & total bandwidth uses?

Tags: asp.net, .net, windows-server-2008, asp.net-4.0, performancecounter

I am using ASP.NET 4.0 on Windows 2008 R2 Server.

I want to measure two thing:

1. Is existing hardware enough to serve growing user load.
2. How much hardware (in terms for RAM & Processor), I need to upgrade so that the site working fine.

**I am already monitoring "Sessions Active", "Available MBytes", "% Processor Time", "Requests/Sec", "Requests Queued".**

Comment: Unfortunately it is not as easy and 30% CPU and 30% memory equates to 1/3 capacity.  Add simulated load and watch Requested Queued.  When that begins to spike look at what the bottle neck is (e.g. CPU, memory, IO).

Answer (score 0):

Both your questions cannot be answered by performance counters alone. You need to factor in "what is a reasonable response time when under a specified load?"<sup>1</sup>

If you want every request to be completely in 0.1s you are going to need significantly more hardware that to complete all in 2s.

The best approach is to load test (higher Visual Studio editions include tools for this) are look at loading (performance counters) *and* time to complete requests.

Remember to include:

- Database responsiveness (it could be the the web server is easily handling the lead, but all the delays are waiting on database operations).
- Is the same web server also serving static content: would serving these from a separate server help?

---

<sup>1</sup> Clearly more requests will lower performance, but by specifying you make it possible to have a repeatable test which is critical to determine if a change has improved performance (or not).

Comment: We have already done load testing for supporting 1000 concurrent user one year ago. But now the user load has increased to 11,000 visits per day from 4000 visits per day. So, we want to have an idea of average & max concurrent users, so that we can plan accordingly.